# $\mathrm{i}\sin(\varphi)=-\mathrm{i}\sin(\mathrm{i}z)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

The whole task is to proof this:

> $$\sinh(z)=-\mathrm{i}\sin(\mathrm{i}z)$$

I used the definition of Euler-Formula und the Moivre-Theorem:

$$\begin{align*} \sinh(z)&=\frac{1}{2}(e^z-e^{-z}) \qquad \vert z=\varphi \mathrm{i}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{\mathrm{i}\varphi}-e^{-{\varphi\mathrm{i}}})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\varphi)+\mathrm{i}\sin(\varphi)-\cos(\varphi)+\mathrm{i}\sin(\varphi))\\
&=\mathrm{i}\sin(\varphi)\\
\end{align*}$$

And unfortunately the last (probably) easy steps are missing. Hints?

Comment: Please show use your intermediate steps, we cannot read your mind.

Comment: Your solution is right, but you need to express the final result in terms of $z$.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this too, but how? If I resubstitute with $\varphi=\frac{z}{i}$ I don't know how to get the right solution.

Comment: You are very very close.

Comment: Sorry man, I can't see it! I get $\mathrm{i}\sin(\frac{z}{\mathrm{i}})$. Is there a rule to get the solution?

Comment: What about $\frac zi=-iz$ ?

Comment: Ahhh, yeah right. Shame on me. Thanks Yves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sinh(z) = \dfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2} = -i\dfrac{e^{i^2z} - e^{-i^2z}}{2i} = -i\dfrac{e^{i(iz)} - e^{-i(iz)}}{2i} = -i\sin(iz).$$

Answer (score 0):

Write down definitions:

$$\begin{cases}&i\sin z=i\cfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\cfrac{e^{iz}-e^{iz}}2=\sinh iz\\{}\\
&-i\sin iz=-i\cfrac{e^{-z}-e^z}{2i}=\cfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}2=\sinh z\end{cases}$$

So there is in one shot both your proof and also a disproof of the equality in your question's title.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it is easier to start from the right hand side of the equation.

$$-i\sin iz=-i \dfrac{1}{2i}(e^{-z}-e^z )$$
$$=\dfrac{e^z -e^{-z}}{2}=\sinh{z}$$

Comment: This is not an answer, and would barely qualify as a comment. Besides, why delete the very same "answer" you posted minutes ago, and repost again now (-1).

Comment: Anyway, the hint is a good one. Should be kept as a comment.

Comment: @dxiv for the former one, my reputation is less 1(now less 5) from the privilege of comment under a question, and ; for the latter one, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @dxiv maybe just now I just deleted it by mistake.

Comment: @user8012403 You can always see your own deleted answers (and 10k+ rep users can, too). It's always advised to *edit* an already posted answer, rather than reposting new ones on the same theme.

Comment: @dxiv thanks for noticing. I'm just a new user so I'm not very familiar with SE's rules. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use $z=(-i)iz$ and

$$\sinh z=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}2=\frac{e^{(-i)iz}-e^{-(-i)iz}}2=-i\frac{e^{i\cdot iz}-e^{-i\cdot iz}}{2i}=-i\sin iz.$$

Comment: Crossed with @DarthGeek.